# Tailored formula for 3 variables with different scales

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I'm not quite sure what this is called, but here's my problem. I have 3 self-reported variables with 3 different measurement ranges.

**Mood**: range -3 to 3

**Energy**: range 0 to 4

**Enjoyment**: range 0 to 4

What would be the best formula for these variables so that the resulting index reflexes highest values for places where:
**Mood is the highest** & **Energy is the lowest** & **Enjoyment is the highest**

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The index scale would be a real number with a <0;1> interval.

If it could be done, I would like the index scale to reflect the differences as proportionally as possible (in each step where the mood and joy is higher and energy is lower, there will be a proportional increase in the index, with in-between steps where all the varibles go in either direction). I am sorry, I am describing it a bit clumsily. I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: Consider a function of the form $f(x) = \frac{(a+3)b}{c}$ where $a = \text{mood}$, $b = \text{enjoyment}$ and $c = \text{energy}$.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer This gives me division by zero error where energy is 0. Also, the index scale seems to exaggerate or underestimate. I would like the index scale to reflect the differences proportionally.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider $f(x) = \frac{(a+3)b}{c+1}$ instead.